# Java bounded wildcard in return type

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I've read in various places including [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#Should%20I%20use%20wildcards%20in%20the%20return%20type%20of%20a%20method?) that having a bounded wildcard in a method return type is a bad idea.  However, I can't find a way to avoid it with my class.  Am I missing something?

The situation looks something like this:

```
class EnglishReaderOfPublications {

    private final Publication<? extends English> publication;

    EnglishReaderOfPublications(Publication<? extends English> publication) {
        this.publication = publication;
    }

    void readPublication() {
        publication.omNomNom();
    }

    Publication<? extends English> getPublication() {
        return publication;
    }
}
```

In summary, a class that I want to be able to *consume* any publication that is in some variant to English.  The class needs to allow access to the publication from outside but, ideally, the callers of `getPublication` wouldn't want the result as a bounded wildcard.  They would be happy with `Publication<English>`.

Is there a way round this?

Comment: Item 28 in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" recommends: "Do not use wildcard types as return types."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bounded wildcards are contagious, which is what the page you link to seems to lament. Well, there's no denying that... but I guess I don't see it as such a big problem.

There are many cases where I return a bounded wildcard exactly *because* it's contagious. The JDK, for better or worse (I say for worse, but that's a different soap box :) ) doesn't have interfaces for read-only collections. If I return a `List<Foo>` that I don't want people modifying (maybe it's even safely wrapped in `Collections.unmodifiableList`), there's no way to declare that in my return signature. As a poor-man's workaround, I'll often return `List<? extends Foo>`. It's still possible to try to modify that list by removing elements or inserting `null`, but at least the fact that you can't `add(new Foo())` serves as a bit of a reminder that this list is probably read-only.

More generally, I think returning something with a bounded return type is perfectly reasonable if you really want the call site to have restricted access to the object.

Another example would be a thread-safe queue that you hand off to different threads, where one thread is a producer and the other is a consumer. If you give the producer a `Queue<? super Foo>`, it's clear that you intend them to put items into it (and not take items out). Likewise, if you give the consumer a `Queue<? extends Foo>`, it's clear you intend them to take items out (and not put items in).

Answer (score 5):

Can you use a bounded type parameter in the class declaration?

```
class EnglishReaderOfPublications<E extends English> { ...
```

Then you can use this type parameter everywhere you have the wildcard parameter.

Comment: I could but I'm not sure it helps in my case.  I have a heterogenous collection of these English readers and I want to get the publications from them when all I care about is that they are `Publication<English>`.  I guess my question is more about why `Publication<English>` isn't the same as `Publication<? extends English>`.  I get why this is for collections (you might add something that satisfied the wildcard but violated the real type) but, as Publication doesn't offer any way to change the language at runtime I'm not really *feeling* why this would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"ideally, the callers of getPublication wouldn't want the result as a bounded wildcard. They would be happy with `Publication<English>`."

Why "wouldn't" they want it? Would they "be happy" with `Publication<? extends English>`? The question is really what these callers need to do with this Publication object. If all they do is get things out of it, then `Publication<? extends English>` is sufficient, and it is better because it is more general. However, if they need to put things into it, then you can't use `Publication<? extends English>`.

Comment: Basically because of the pollution.  The calling code gets each publication by calling `getPublication` and puts it in a `Set`.  At the moment I'm having to pass around `Set<Publication<? extends English>>` which is making my code hard to read.  Maybe I'm being fussy.

Comment: Harder to read, but more general to use. I agree that the syntax is unfortunately verbose. If these classes/methods are just in your own code, you can go for the easy-to-read approach if you like it better. If you're writing an API that you expect others to read, it's pretty important to get the wildcards right -- because it would be a shame if someone had a Publication<? extends English> and couldn't use it in your API because of "lazy" (or "pretty", if you like) typing.