# Java: Can't return a generic Collection with the parameter extending the return type

Tags: java, generics

first post here...

Here is a generic class I have defined:

```
public class TimeSeries<T extends Number> extends TreeMap<Integer, T>{
     ...

     public Collection<Number> data() {
         return this.values();  
     }
}
```

A bit of context. TimeSeries is basically a specific kind of TreeMap, where the keys are Integers and the values are Numbers.

My issue is that the data method breaks with the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: Collection<T> cannot be converted to Collection<Number>
    return this.values();   
                      ^
where T is a type-variable: T extends Number declared in class TimeSeries
```

values method just returns a Collection of T. Why exactly can't I return this out of the method if I have specifically stated that T extends Number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `this.values()`?

Comment: The return type is: Collection<T>

Answer (score 4):

You have to return any of these types:

```
public Collection<? extends Number> data() {
    return this.values();  
}
```

or

```
public Collection<T> data() {
    return this.values();  
}
```

Think of it this way:

```
TimeSeries<Integer> series = new TimeSeries<>();

// You want this:
Collection<Number> data = series.data();

// Oops, compiles, but not an Integer:
data.add(Long.valueOf(42));
```

More information:

- [Collection<? extends T> vs Collection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28464614/521799)
- [Returning Collection<? extends Type> vs Collection<Type>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18382694/521799)
- [When do Java generics require <? extends T> instead of <T> and is there any downside of switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/897935/521799)
- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/521799)

Comment: It is also worse to mentioning that <T> is not absolutely necessary in this context. Thus you can specify it without generic:
`public class TimeSeries extends TreeMap<Integer, Number>`

Comment: @nesteant: That's not true. The OP *wants* to have a generic `TimeSeries<T extends Number>` type, which makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to return `Collection<Number>`, you can use `Collections.unmodifiableCollection` to make a read-only view over `Collection<T>`:

```
public Collection<Number> data() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(this.values());
}
```

`unmodifiableCollection` and its cousins in `Collections` class are very handy for making read-only views as collection of supertype over collections of subtype.

Comment: @LukasEder What version of java are you using?  unmodifiableCollection's signature is `static <T> Collection<T> unmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends T> c)`.   It compiles on every version of java I tried and works perfectly well.

Comment: Interesting, my bad. I seem to have run into an Eclipse compiler issue. Will verify, but your solution seems fine