# Java parallel inheritance hierarchies with generics and covariant returns

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Let's say I have these two inheritance hierarchies:

```
class EntityA { ... }
class EntityB extends EntityA { ... }

class EntityAPrime extends AbstractPrime<EntityA> { ... }
class EntityBPrime extends EntityAPrime { ... }
```

I'd also like covariant return types:

```
public class EntityA {
  public EntityAPrime prime() {
    return new EntityAPrime();
  }
}

public class EntityB extends EntityA {
  @Override
  public EntityBPrime prime() {
    return new EntityBPrime();
  }
}
```

So far so good.

The problem is I'd like `EntityBPrime` to ultimately extend `AbstractPrime<EntityB>` but since it extends `EntityAPrime` it ultimately extends `AbstractPrime<EntityA>`.

I can make `EntityAPrime` and `EntityBPrime` generic, but then I lose covariant return types:

```
public class EntityA {
  public EntityAPrime<EntityA> prime() {
    return new EntityAPrime();
  }
}

public class EntityB extends EntityA {
  @Override
  public EntityBPrime<B> prime() {  // ERROR: EntityBPrime extends EntityAPrime
    return new EntityBPrime();      // but can't substitute <EntityB> for <EntityA>
  }
}
```

Everything works if I return a bound wildcard but there's [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8966502/152061) associated with that and I wouldn't be able to call a particular setter on `AbstractPrime`.

Another idea I had is to make `EntityA` and `EntityB` themselves generic.

```
public class EntityA<T extends EntityA> {
  public EntityAPrime<T> prime() { ... }
}

public class EntityB<T extends EntityB> extends EntityA<T> {
    @Override
    public EntityBPrime<T> prime() { ... }
}
```

This should work but I think it will get messy (we have over 100 entities that would use a similar pattern).

So, is there any way to:

- keep covariant returns
- not use generics on `EntityA` and `EntityB`
- not have `prime()` return a bound wildcard
- and have `EntityBPrime` ultimately extend `AbstractPrime<EntityB>` instead of `AbstractPrime<EntityA>`

Note: the prime classes are generated code, but I have control over the code that does the generating.

Comment: Not unless you break inheritance between A and B. Can you use composition instead?

Comment: @EricStein The entities were modeled with inheritance in mind, and map to tables that way. That's really good thinking though.

Comment: I think you're up the creek, then. Extension strikes again. :-(

Comment: I think it may be typos, but there are lots of problem in your source code: EntityBPrime should bear type param but now is not; EntityA#prime() is return raw type of EntityAPrime.... etc

Comment: @AdrianShum ack you're right. I fixed a mistake in the question which should clear things up considerably. Sorry about that. I'm not in favor of raw types.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's slightly confusing that both your interfaces and classes are called `A` and `B`. So, I've renamed the classes as `AImpl` and `BImpl` respectively. Also, your classes `APrime` and `BPrime` are not typed (they need to be), so I've assumed they are typed on `<T extends A>` and `<T extends B>` respectively (if I've misunderstood your intentions/objectives/requirements, I apologise).

```
private interface A {}
private interface B extends A {}
private abstract class AbstractPrime<T extends A>{}
private class APrime<T extends A> extends AbstractPrime<T>{}
private class BPrime<T extends B> extends APrime<T>{}
private class AImpl {...}
private class BImpl {...}
```

My first instinct was, as you had considered, to type the implementations on the interfaces. This would work:

```
private class AImpl<T extends A> {
  public APrime<T> prime(){
    return new APrime<>();
  }
}

private class BImpl<T extends B> extends AImpl<T> {
  public BPrime<T> prime(){
    return new BPrime<>();
  }
}
```

However, if you have typed `APrime` on `<T extends A>` and `BPrime` on `<T extends B>`, do you need the return type of `prime()` to be typed? Might the following solution work for you?

```
class APrime<T extends A> extends AbstractPrime<T>{}
class BPrime<T extends B> extends APrime<T>{}

public class AImpl {
  public APrime prime(){
    return new APrime<>();
  }
}

public class BImpl extends AImpl {
  public BPrime prime(){
    return new BPrime<>();
  }
}
```

I guess the answer to that is somewhat whether you envision needing the following:

```
private interface C extends B {}

public void main(String[] args) {
  BPrime<C> prime = new BImpl<C>().prime(); // do you need this?
  BPrime<B> prime = new BImpl<>().prime(); // do you need this?


  BPrime prime = new BImpl().prime(); or is this sufficient...?
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for taking the time to help. +1. Also, I clarified the question some. There's no interfaces, and I'd like to avoid `AImpl<T extends A>` where `AImpl` is an entity (see question for slightly more detail on this), though we can probably agree making the entities generic sounds like the way to fix it. I'd also like to avoid raw types. Finally, to answer both "do you need this?" questions, I don't need the first, but do want the second one. The problem is I can't have it without making `AImpl` generic.

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in the comment, there are lots of places that type params are omitted, which makes the whole story doesn't look right.

First, your Primes should at least looks like:

```
class EntityAPrime<T extends EntityA> extends AbstractPrime<T> {}

class EntityBPrime<T extends EntityB> extends EntityAPrime<T> {}
```

Then the question comes to your entity

```
class EntityA {
  public EntityAPrime<????> prime();  <- What should be the reasonable type param here?
}

class EntityB extends EntityA {
  public EntityBPrime<????> prime();  <- Same here
}
```

The answer is dependent on your design.

I don't see how your second choice is messier than your original one (given the original one is REAL messy)

You may consider this  (Not tested, and whether or not it is right greatly depending on your design, but at least type params looks reasonable to me):

```
public class Entity<T> {
  public Prime<T> prime();
}

public class AbstractEntityA<T extends EntityA> extends Entity<T> {
  @Override
  public AbstractAPrime<T> prime();
}

public class EntityA extends AbstractEntityA<EntityA>{
  public EntityAPrime prime() { ... }
}

public class EntityB extends AbstractEntityA<EntityB> {
  public EntityBPrime prime() {...}
}


public class AbstractAPrime<T extends EntityA> extends AbstractPrime<T> {}

public class EntityAPrime extends AbstractAPrime<EntityA>{}
public class EntityBPrime extends AbstractAPrime<EntityB>{}
```

In brief, move content in your original EntityA to an abstract class, for which to be extended by EntityA (mostly just a plain extends) and EntityB (overriding and adding more things). Same applies to Prime.

Comment: I had a mistake in the question that's now fixed. Thanks for noticing, and for taking the time to answer. +1. Making the entities generic does seem like it would solve the issue, but in the question I mentioned it would be messy. We have 100+ entities and I thought they'd all have to become generic. Furthermore, Hibernate won't return generic entities and I'm not sure what Spring Data would do. While typing this though I realized only entities in an inheritance hierarchy have to be generic and we don't have too many of them.