# Bounded wildcard in return type of static factory pattern

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I've read in Effective Java that you should not use bounded wildcards as return types, but I don't know how should I do this then. The only way my code compiles is by using `RequestCloner<? extends HttpUriRequest>` as return type in the static factory. Am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround?

NOTE: One thing to be noted is that `HttpUriRequest` has the method `setHeader`, but only `HttpPost` has the method `setEntity`.

```
abstract class RequestCloner<T extends HttpUriRequest> {

  protected T clonedRequest;

  private enum RequestType {
    GET, POST, DELETE
  }

  static RequestCloner<? extends HttpUriRequest> newInstance(
      String type, String url) {
    RequestType requestType = RequestType.valueOf(type);
    switch (requestType) {
    case GET:
      return new GetRequestCloner(url);
    case POST:
      return new PostRequestCloner(url);
    case DELETE:
      return new DeleteRequestCloner(url);
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
          "Method '%s' not supported",
          type));
    }
  }

  public abstract HttpUriRequest clone(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws IOException;

  protected void cloneHeaders(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Enumeration<String> e = servletRequest.getHeaderNames();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String header = e.nextElement();
        if (!header.equalsIgnoreCase("Content-Length")
                && !header.equalsIgnoreCase("Authorization")
                && !header.equalsIgnoreCase("Host")) {
            clonedRequest.setHeader(new BasicHeader(header, servletRequest.getHeader(header)));
        }
    }
  }
}

...

class GetRequestCloner extends RequestCloner<HttpGet> {

  GetRequestCloner(String url) {
    this.clonedRequest = new HttpGet(url);
  }

  @Override
  public HttpUriRequest clone(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    cloneHeaders(servletRequest);
    return clonedRequest;
  }
}

...

class PostRequestCloner extends RequestCloner<HttpPost> {

  private static final int MAX_STR_LEN = 1024;

  PostRequestCloner(String url) {
    this.clonedRequest = new HttpPost(url);
  }

  @Override
  public HttpUriRequest clone(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws IOException {
    cloneHeaders(servletRequest);
    cloneBody(servletRequest);
    return clonedRequest;
  }

  private void cloneBody(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            servletRequest.getInputStream(),
            "UTF-8"));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && sb.length() < MAX_STR_LEN) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
    clonedRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(sb.toString(), "UTF-8"));
  }
}

...

class DeleteRequestCloner extends RequestCloner<HttpDelete> {

  DeleteRequestCloner(String url) {
    this.clonedRequest = new HttpDelete(url);
  }

  @Override
  public HttpUriRequest clone(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    cloneHeaders(servletRequest);
    return clonedRequest;
  }
}
```

Comment: How is `clonedRequest` used in `RequestCloner`? It's not clear from the code why `RequestCloner` needs to be generic

Comment: @NamshubWriter  I added the rest of the code. I'm cloning an `HttpServletRequest` to Apache httpclient library, and each request type has it's own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, your class does not need to be generic. Looking further, there is the odd issue where the caller passes in a URL to create a cloner, then passes a `HttpServletRequest` (which could in theory be a different type of request) into the clone method.

I can see two kinds of solutions, depending on whether you really need `RequestCloner` to be generic.

**If RequestCloner Does Not Need To Be Generic**

Change the base class as follows:

```
abstract class RequestCloner {

  private enum RequestType {
    GET, POST, DELETE
  }

  public static HttpUriRequest cloneRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
        throws IOException {
    RequestCloner cloner = createCloner(servletRequest);
    String uri = servletRequest.getRequestURI();
    return cloner.clone(uri, servletRequest);
  }

  private static RequestCloner createCloner(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    RequestType requestType = RequestType.valueOf(servletRequest. getMethod());
    switch (requestType) {
    case GET:
      return new GetRequestCloner();
    case POST:
      return new PostRequestCloner();
    case DELETE:
      return new DeleteRequestCloner();
    default:
      throw new AssertionFailedError(String.format(
          "RequestType '%s' not supported", requestType));
    }
  }

  protected abstract HttpUriRequest clone(
      String uri, HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
      throws IOException;

  protected final void cloneHeaders(
      HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
      HttpUriRequest clonedRequest) { // note addition of parameter
    // same code as before, but modify the passed-in clonedRequest
  }
}
```

Subclasses of `RequestCloner` would override `clone()`, optionally changing the return value to return a subclass of `HttpUriRequest`:

```
class PostRequestCloner extends RequestCloner {
  private static final int MAX_STR_LEN = 1024;

  @Override
  protected HttpPost clone(
      String uri, HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
      throws IOException {
    HttpPost clonedRequest = new HttpPost(uri);
    cloneHeaders(servletRequest, clonedRequest);
    cloneBody(servletRequest, clonedRequest);
    return clonedRequest;
  }

  ...
}
```

The disadvantages of the above solution is the return value of `cloneRequest()` is the same for a GET request as a POST request.

If you prefer, you can **remove the switch by adding code to the enum**:

```
abstract class RequestCloner {

  private enum RequestType {
    GET(new GetRequestCloner()),
    POST(new PostRequestCloner()),
    DELETE(new DeleteRequestCLoner());

    private final RequestCloner requestCloner;

    private RequestType(RequestCloner requestCloner) {
      this.requestCloner = requestCloner();
    }
  }

  public static HttpUriRequest cloneRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
        throws IOException {
    RequestType requestType = RequestType.valueOf(servletRequest. getMethod());
    String uri = servletRequest.getRequestURI();
    return requestType.requestCloner.clone(uri, servletRequest);
  }

  ...
}
```

If you want the return value to depend on the type of request, then the caller will need to either specify some kind of type token, explicitly reference the subclass of `RequestCloner`, or add one static method to `RequestCloner` for each type of request.

**If RequestCloner Needs To Be Generic**

Given the code in the question, the  only benefit of making `RequestCloner` generic is to make the return value of `clone()` different for GET or POST.

To do that, you have two options

1. Making the subclasses (and their constructors) public.
2. Replace your `newInstance()` method with multiple creational methods

Here is an example of option 2:

```
public static RequestCloner<HttpPost> forPostRequest(String URL) {
  return new PostRequestCloner(URL);
}
```

Comment: But this way I'd have to add the proper `clonedRequest` property to each class (`HttpGet`, `HttpPost`...), instead of having only one property in the abstract class and inherit it, which is how I'd like to do it if possible.

Comment: @carcaret You don't need to make `getClonedRequest` abstract if you are willing to add a field in the base class that is shadowed by the subclasses. That's a very small amount of code duplication (also, my solution allows you to make your fields `final`, which is a good thing to do where possible). If that duplication would allow you to make `RequestCloner` non-generic, it's well worth it IMHO.

Comment: @carcaret In case you didn't notice, I updated my answer. Looks like you have multiple good answers to choose from

Comment: What I'd like is that the client wouldn't have to check the type of the request. Using the creational methods, it has to perform a `switch` to choose the right method, and I'd prefer this logic to be in the `RequestCloner`. Is that posible?

Comment: @carcaret Yes, that can be done with the first option I suggested: remove the generics from the class

Comment: @carcaret I updated my answer to provide an even simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to accomplish what you want, with a slight change: you'd need to pass the right `Class` object to the factory method:

```
abstract class RequestCloner<T extends HttpUriRequest> {

    protected T clonedRequest;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <U extends HttpUriRequest, V extends RequestCloner<U>> V newInstance(
        U request, String url) {

        Class<U> clazz = request.getClass();
        Class<V> clz = null;
        if (HttpGet.class == clazz) {
            clz = GetRequestCloner.class;
        } else if (HttpPost.class == clazz) {
            clz = PostRequestCloner.class;
        } // etc

        try {
            return clz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Factory error", e);
        }
    }

    // no need for this method to be abstract
    public T cloneRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws IOException {
        cloneHeaders(servletRequest);
        return clonedRequest;
    }

    protected void cloneHeaders(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        Enumeration<String> e = servletRequest.getHeaderNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String header = e.nextElement();
            if (!header.equalsIgnoreCase("Content-Length")
                    && !header.equalsIgnoreCase("Authorization")
                    && !header.equalsIgnoreCase("Host")) {
                clonedRequest.setHeader(new BasicHeader(header, servletRequest.getHeader(header)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, GET would be as follows:

```
class GetRequestCloner extends RequestCloner<HttpGet> {

    GetRequestCloner(String url) {
        this.clonedRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    }

    // no need to override cloneRequest here
}
```

And POST:

```
class PostRequestCloner extends RequestCloner<HttpPost> {

    PostRequestCloner(String url) {
        this.clonedRequest = new HttpPost(url);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpPost cloneRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws IOException {
        super.cloneRequest(servletRequest);
        cloneBody(servletRequest); // Adding POST's body here
        return clonedRequest;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GetRequestCloner getCloner = RequestCloner.newInstance(servletRequest, url);
HttpGet get = getCloner.cloneRequest(servletRequest);

PostRequestCloner postCloner = RequestCloner.newInstance(servletRequest, url);
HttpPost post = postCloner.cloneRequest(servletRequest);
```

Note: I've changed `clone()` method name to `cloneRequest()` so that it doesn't clash with Java's `Clonable.clone()`.

Comment: Thanks Federico. I find one issue with this approach. The client now must know which class maps to each request type (if I'm cloning a GET I have to pass `GetRequestCloner.class`), instead of letting the factory method decide it (using for instance `servletRequest.getMethod()`).

Comment: @carcaret You can easily overcome that: instead of mapping by a simple `String` (type in your case), you could get the right cloner by receiving the actual request as an argument in your factory method. I'll update my answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The problem is that in `newInstance` you are expecting a `U extends HttpUriRequest`, but what I've got is a simple `HttpServletRequest`, which I want to clone to a `HttpUriRequest`, so in the `if` statement I still won't have the `HttpGet.class` to compare to.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this?

```
static <V extends HttpUriRequest, K extends RequestCloner<V>> K newInstance((String type, String url)
```

Here there is not wildcard used in return type, but it's always not bad idea to return wildcards.

> More generally, I think returning something with a bounded return type is perfectly reasonable if you really want the call site to have restricted access to the object.

Please [**refer this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8967261/1326692) for more details.

Comment: If this were possible, a call like `RequestCloner.<HttpGet>newInstance("POST", url)` would not be type safe

Comment: @AndyTurner, You are right but, I think it is not the PO's question, the case you mentioned was also possible with PO's given example.

Comment: It simply can't compile though with your suggestion though. Each of the lines e.g. `return new GetRequestCloner(url);` would report that the type was incompatible with `RequestCloner<K>`.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia Indeed, with this solution I get the message Andy is saying.

Comment: @carcaret, see updated answer, are you still getting error?

Comment: @AndyTurner, You are right, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia that still won't work. It's fundamentally not type safe, so the compiler won't allow it.